# How to prevent duplicates abp.notify.warn toastr?

Tags: typescript, abp, toastr

I have been trying to prevent the same warning message from appearing.
[multiple duplicate warning popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLP8.png)
But I don't want to stop duplicate for every popup. Only for one of them.

**CageAuto.ts**

```
getMeasure(): IMeasurement {
    [...]
    if (heightPos <= 1) {
       throw new Error("Posterior Height is less than or equal to 1mm");
    }
    [...]
}
```

**toolBase.ts**

```
updateMeasures(): void {
    try {
        this.measurement = this.getMeasure();
    } catch (e) {
        abp.notify.warn(e, '', { preventDuplicates: true, timeOut: 1000 });
        return;
    }
}
```

I uses the ABP Framework : [ABP warn](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/JavaScript-API/Notify). It uses the library Toastr : [toastr github](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).
The option

```
preventDuplicates: true
```

does not work, and I don't know why.
However, the other option

```
timeOut: 1000
```

is working fine.

What am i missing? What did i do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our discussion, you have to pass a string in the first parameter of `warn`. In the classic [`Error` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), you can use the [message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message) property. Like this:

```
updateMeasures(): void {
    try {
        this.measurement = this.getMeasure();
    } catch (e) {
        abp.notify.warn(e.message, '', { preventDuplicates: true, timeOut: 1000 });
        return;
    }
}
```

Since the value `e` in the `catch` is not necessary an error object, you can check if message is defined and pass a default error message like this:

```
abp.notify.warn(e.message ?? 'Default error message', '', { preventDuplicates: true, timeOut: 1000 });
```